# Execute terminal command using ">" in java

Tags: java

I want to redirect the output to text file using `Runtime.getRuntime().exec("ls > 1.txt")` but it doesn't work. I tried by passing string array instead of string but it didn't work.Other commands such as opening `open` is working fine.

Is there any solution to redirect the output to a text file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `Runtime.exec()` is bad practice, you should use a [`ProcessBuilder`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html).
`ProcessBuilder` has a `.redirectOutput()` method which enables you to define where you want to receive the process' output.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Is there any method to append the data to the existing file like using ">>" ?

Comment: Yes there is : the `.redirectOutput()` expects a `ProcessBuilder.Redirect`, which can be either `ProcessBuilder.Redirect.to(File f)`, overwriting the file, or `ProcessBuilder.Redirect.appendTo(File f)` where it will append as would `>>`